# Using recursion call for building patterns

Tags: python, recursion

Currently I learning recursion in Python. There is this question in my tutorials that I cannot do. I am supposed to print this patterns using recursion. But I can't seem to do it.

**Current solution: 5th pattern is incorrect**

The pattern I need to create:

[image: screenshot of pattern]

My code so far:

```
def main():
    rec_front(1,2)

def rec_front(start,end):
    if start >= end:
        rec_back(end)
    else:
        string = '*' * start
        print(string)
        rec_front(start+1, end)

def rec_back(end):
    if end == 0:
        return "*"
    else:
        string = "*" * end
        print(string)
        rec_back(end-1)

main()
```

Comment: Please help me! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

A fairly simple recursive function would be

```
def pat(n):
    if n > 0:
        pat(n-1)
        print('*' * n)
        pat(n-1)

pat(1)
*
pat(2)
*
**
*
pat(3)
*
**
*
***
*
**
*
pat(4)
*
**
*
***
*
**
*
****
*
**
*
***
*
**
*
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick reponse! But what I was thought in school, requires a base case and recursive case. Do you have a solution for that?

Comment: The base case is the omitted (and unnecessary) `else`-block (`n <= 0` -> do nothing). The recursive case is the `if`-block.

Comment: I see. Also when pat (5) it doesn't follow the pattern anymore. I'm not sure why

Comment: Maybe you showed to few example cases. It does work for me, at least the way I understand the pattern. Otherwise you probably already dislike `pat(4)`, don't you?

Comment: Is there another way of solving this problem?

Comment: pattern 4
*
**
*
***
*
****
*
***
*
**
*

pattern 5
*
**
*
***
*
****
*
*****
*
****
*
***
*
**
*

Comment: Then I don't see why for 3, it isn't `* ** *** ** *`. Why go back to 1 star there? The recursive pattern that emerges from the 3 samples seems to suit my interpretation better. But that's taste :)

Answer (score 0):

```
def main():
    start = 2
    pattern = 3
    printasc(start, pattern)


def printasc(start, end):
    if start > end:
        print('*')
        printdesc(end - 1)
    else:
        print('*')
        string = '*' * start
        print(string)
        printasc(start+1, end)
        


def printdesc(num):
    if num == 1:
        return '*'
    else:
        string = '*' * num
        print(string)
        print('*')
        printdesc(num-1)

main()
```

Comment: Hi, could you explain the way your code works with code comments, or textual details around the code? OP admits to be at learning stage, it would greatly help him--and other users passing by--if you provided clarification.